# how to split long code lines in SIL script language

Tags: jira

I'm wondering how I'd splite the code lines in SIL?
Couldn't find anything regarding this in doc

```
string [] keys = selectIssues("project = jgate AND issuetype in (SMSGateTemplate 
    , SMSGateTemplateCreate, SMSGateTemplateDelete, SMSGateTemplateUpdate)");
```

in this example i need to split string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just figureg out that i can split

```
string someString = "word and another word";
```

by splitting text in paranthesis to several string with + operator like this:

```
string someString = "word and " 
                   + "another word";
```

thats solves my problem with long string readability